# xlsx.core.min.js:13 Uncaught Error: Unsupported file NaN

Tags: jquery, excel, xlsx, alasql

I facing a error using alasql with xlsx.core.js.
code is

```
alasql('select * from xlsx("Leads.xlsx")',[],function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

error that comes up is.=> Uncaught Error: Unsupported file NaN
how can i resolve this error.
or suggest me any other file from which i can access the data in an excel file.

Library is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/alasql.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
```

One important thing, this code was completely run by last night, and when i run it today, it was giving this error.

Thanks.
don't mind.. i am poor in English. and new to stack overflow.

Comment: i got solution by using only xlsx.core.js lib..first convert the file in binary using lib than use it with javascript objects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solution by using only **xlsx.core.js** lib..first convert the file in binary using lib than use it with JavaScript objects..